# module import error in pandas

Tags: python, module, pandas, importerror

I installed pandas module. It required the latest version of numpy, and I had the old one pip installed the pandas module which also installs all its dependencies including numpy. When I try to import pandas module in my code, I get the error below:

```
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py:35: 
UserWarning: Module dateutil was already imported from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/dateutil/__init__.pyc, but /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages is being added to sys.path
from pkg_resources import resource_stream
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Python-3.py", line 10, in <module>
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
import pandas.core.config_init
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pandas/core/config_init.py", line 4, in <module>
from pandas.core.format import detect_console_encoding
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 25, in <module>
from pandas.tseries.period import PeriodIndex
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pandas/tseries/period.py", line 7, in <module>
import pandas.tseries.offsets as offsets
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pandas/tseries/offsets.py", line 3, in <module>
from pandas.tseries.tools import to_datetime
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 19, in <module>
dateutil.__version__ == '2.0'):  # pragma: no cover
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

I'm not able to figure out why am I getting this error and how to correct it.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have two copies of Python installed (one in `/System/Library` and one in `/Library/`), and something is getting confused about which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

i came across the same problem, when trying to import QTSK package,
and the exact same message was displayed.

i found that the message is not displayed, when:

1. import numpy before import QSTK,
2. when i ran python from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages,
   because the pkg_resources is in 
   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.32-py2.7.egg.
3. site.path when i was running python in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:

   > > > print("\n".join(sys.path))
   > > >       /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.32-py2.7.egg
   > > >       /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle-5.1.2-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
   > > >       
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
   > > >       /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL
   > > >       /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info
4. site.path when i was running outside /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

   > > > print("\n".join(sys.path))
   > > >       
   > > >       /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.32-py2.7.egg
   > > >       /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cx_Oracle-5.1.2-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
   > > >       /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
   > > >       /Users/ssgam/QSTK
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
   > > >       /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
   > > >       /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL
   > > >       /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info

   note that the first line is empty, and is not /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages.
5. looks like a problem with the order of loading/lookup for packages.
6. after setting

   PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.32-py2.7.egg
   export PYTHONPATH

   the problem is gone.

hth with your problem as well ...
sam